# do any computer languages know the difference between checking for variable that doesn't exist, and checking for existence?

Tags: python, functional-programming, computer-science

something I find weird in python is the inability to do:

```
In [3]: if x:
   ...:     print y
   ...:     

----> 1 if x:
      2     print y
      3 

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

This leads to declaring things as None or whatnot, or using try/except which is more code in both cases. My friend said once "you don't want to be able to check something that doesn't exist", and I disagree because you could check for if the item exists compared to if an existing item has anything. There's a difference between a fictional character that never existed, and a deceased person that isn't alive right now.

Do any languages allow this and is it powerful, or cause problems?

Comment: this would be considered an antipattern in any language even languages that allow it ...  there are other mechanisms to test existance if thats what you want to do ... but you usually want to just check the value ... if you did this you cannot tell if you did not enter the if statement because the variable did not exist or if you did not enter the if statement due to the variable being "falsey"

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those things that seems like a good idea when you're new but is almost always unuseful, like creating variables numbered `item1` to `itemN` when you should be using a list. You can do it:

```
try:
    x
except NameError:
    defined = False
else:
    defined = True
```

but there's usually a better way to achieve your underlying goal.

Answer (score 1):

Tcl allows you to check if a variable exists or not:

```
if {[info exists some_variable]} {
    puts "it exists"
} else {
    puts "it does NOT exist"
}
```

I'm not sure I would describe this as "powerful" per se, but it is useful in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1):

any strongly typed language has this because the program wouldn't be able to compile if `x` didnt' already exist

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does - it's called `undefined`.

Though varaibles can still be defined with undefined. It would appear that, within Javascript, at least, there are some really [weird problems](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/) that you can face, but that may be less due to the nature of being undefined and more due to the fact that you can redefine `undefined`.

Comment: That may be what the guy was referring to. He doesn't like javascript in general

Answer (score 0):

Python has this: you can use `locals().get("foo")` to see if "foo" exists in the local scope. same for `globals()`.  if its an attribute, you can use `getattr(o,"foo")` to see if `o` has the attribute `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you distinguish between declared and initialised?  For example, in Perl:

```
use strict;
my $var1;
```

The variable `$var1` is logically declared, but an `if (defined $var1)` test would return false, since it's value is `undef`, the Perl value for uninitialised variables.  The `use strict` will not throw a compilation error, but if we used `$var2` instead then it would.

In Python there is no formal way to declare a variable, and all variables, if not otherwise assigned, are references to the `None` object.  Notice, they are references.  In everyday speech it is often said that they have the *value* None, but that is not strictly correct.

So In Python the correct test is `is`:

```
if x is None:
    ...
```

We are testing if `x` is a reference to `None`, since in Python there is no such thing as an initialised variable.  So *This leads to declaring things as None*, you don't need to explicitly assign `None` (although it can aid readability).

Of course `None` if often used for other purposes, for example as a return value to indicate an error.

Ruby has a similar concept to `None` called `nil`.  However the rules for assignment are a little more complicated.